# Plotting time data on R: Data disappears from plot the second I add limits to x or y axes

Tags: r

I want to plot the time I go to sleep every day versus the date. I'm new to working with date values but I've looked up a bunch on plotting dates and times and have managed to at least plot numerical data vs dates like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3tOG.png)

However, I can't get this to work with time vs date values. If I simply plot time vs date without any limits I get [2] (I added the links to the bottom because I can't add more than 1 apparently)

But when I add limits, the points all disappear even if the data should fit within the limits like in [3].

My data is in the format (there are a lot more columns but I'm excluding them here):

```
Date,Hours.Bio,Sleep
17-Feb,0.5,01:30
18-Feb,1.16,01:30
19-Feb,1.5,03:00
```

Here's my code:

```
#LOAD DATA
progress <- read.csv("../Data/Progress.csv")
progress$Date <- as.Date(progress$Date, format="%d-%b")
progress$Sleep <- as.POSIXct(progress$Sleep, format ="%H:%M") 
#It just doesn't work with as.Date I don't know why
#DATES AND TIME LIMITS FOR PLOTS
StartDate <- as.Date("17/02/2017", format="%d/%m/%Y")
DateSeq <- seq(StartDate, by = "day", length.out = 30)
StartSleep <- as.POSIXct("22:00", format="%H:%M")
SleepSeq <- seq.POSIXt(StartSleep, by = "hour", length.out = 7)
#PLOT (MONTH) BIOLOGY
plot(Hours.Bio~Date, data=progress, xlim=c(DateSeq[1],      
DateSeq[length(DateSeq)]), ylim=c(0, 6), type="l", xlab="Date", 
xaxt='n', ylab="Number of hours", main="Amount of biology studied per day")
axis.Date(1, at=DateSeq, format="%d/%m", las=2, cex.axis=0.9)
#PLOT (MONTH) SLEEP
plot(Sleep~Date, data=progress, type="l", xaxt="n")
axis.Date(1, at=DateSeq, format="%d/%m", las=2, cex.axis=0.9)
```

So the above works although I'm sure there's an easier way to do it. This doesn't work, however:

```
plot(Sleep~Date, data=progress, xlim=c(DateSeq[1], DateSeq[length(DateSeq)]),   
ylim=c(SleepSeq[1], last(SleepSeq)), xlab="Date", xaxt='n', type="l",
 ylab="Bedtime", main="Time I went to sleep over time")
axis.Date(1, at=DateSeq, format="%d/%m", las=2, cex.axis=0.9)
```

It just gets me an empty plot as in [3].
What's going wrong here?

[2]is xiRRS.png
[3]is xrUzE.png

Comment: Where does the function `last` come from?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was editing the function to ask the question here but I have some extras.R thing I load at the start which has a last(vector) function to just select the last value in a vector.
That should be DateSeq[length(DateSeq)] here which I've edited now.

Answer (score 0):

When I evaluate `SleepSeq` I get

```
SleepSeq 
[1] "2017-02-20 22:00:00 EST" "2017-02-20 23:00:00 EST" "2017-02-21 00:00:00 EST"
[4] "2017-02-21 01:00:00 EST" "2017-02-21 02:00:00 EST" "2017-02-21 03:00:00 EST"
[7] "2017-02-21 04:00:00 EST"
```

So the `ylim` on your plot is from "2017-02-20 22:00:00 EST" to "2017-02-21 04:00:00 EST".  In words,  10 PM tonight to 4 AM tomorrow.

When I evaluate `progress$Sleep` I get

```
progress$Sleep
[1] "2017-02-20 01:30:00 EST" "2017-02-20 01:30:00 EST" "2017-02-20 03:00:00 EST"
```

three times in the early morning of today. The latest time in `progress$Sleep` is 19 hours before the earliest time that you are plotting - so your points are off the graph.

**Fix**

One way to fix this is if you went to bed after midnight, add a day.

```
Midnight   = as.POSIXct("00:00", format="%H:%M")
LateNights = which((progress$Sleep - Midnight) < 12)
OneDay     = 24*60*60
progress$Sleep[LateNights] = progress$Sleep[LateNights] + OneDay
```

Now just run your original code.

```
plot(Sleep~Date, data=progress, xlim=c(DateSeq[1], DateSeq[length(DateSeq)]),   
ylim=c(SleepSeq[1], SleepSeq[length(SleepSeq)]), xlab="Date", xaxt='n', type="l",
 ylab="Bedtime", main="Time I went to sleep over time")
axis.Date(1, at=DateSeq, format="%d/%m", las=2, cex.axis=0.9)
```

[image: Bedtime]

Comment: Ooh right that makes sense.
But how would I go about separating the time from the date? I guess the time would always be linked to a specific day. I just want the y-limits of the graph to be from 22:00 to 04:00 but if you use something like seq() to just make a vector of times it isn't accepted because it doesn't match the format of the data.

Comment: @StinkyPeterson - I have updated the answer to include a fix.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fix! I didn't know what which() did so I had to look it up just now to understand. Very nicely done.
I also didn't know you could just add the number of seconds in a day to a POSIXct class just like that